# How to use the IMU raw data, rostopic echo imu

Tags: imu, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have one question regarding using the raw IMU data. Im using a sensor package with laser range finder, IMU and camera. My bag file consists of scans, imu data and images. I would like to know how to use the imu data to calculate the position and angular velocity of the robot. This is the output of the rostopic echo /imu/data

For example

```
header: 
  seq: 24237
  stamp: 
    secs: 1301628270
    nsecs: 972690349
  frame_id: /base_imu
orientation: 
  x: -0.628151834011
  y: 0.0210457909852
  z: -0.0200814530253
  w: -0.777546823025
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.00680741108954
  y: -0.00184269389138
  z: -0.00491618132219
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.43050968647
  y: 0.00864356849343
  z: 9.79496383667
line.........
```

Any help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49299/how-to-use-the-imu-raw-data,-rostopic-echo-imu/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [navigation](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation) stack. There is lots of information and tools to use to calculate robot position, generate maps, and navigate.

Also take a look at the [robot_pose_ekf](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf?distro=fuerte) which fuses IMU data, odometry, and video odometry to calculate position.

In addition, [viso2](http://ros.org/wiki/viso2) is a good package to produce video odometry from your camera images.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-11-28**:
Sorry but I did not found in the navigation stack any info for IMU. Any help???